# How to extend an Enum with an additional interface?

Tags: java, enums

I have an existing enum from another library I cannot change, as follows:

```
    enum PersonTypes {
       ADT("Adult"), CHD("Child"), INF("Infant");
    
       private String value;
       PersonTypes(String value) { this.value = value; }
    }
```

I want to enhance the enum with an interface so supply some functionality. Of course the following code is invalid, but demonstrates what I'm trying to achieve:

```
    enum PrintablePersonTypes implements Printable {
       PersonTypes.ADT, PersonTypes.CHD, PersonTypes.INF;
    
       @Override
       public void printme() {
            sysout("I'm a " + super.value);
       }
    }
```

Lateron like:

```
List<PrintablePersonTypes> list;
list.stream.forEach(p -> o.printme());
```

Is that possible somehow?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Does the `printme` method actually need to be a member of a type, as opposed to e.g. a static method which takes an instance of the enum as a parameter? Something like `list.stream.forEach(p -> printme(p));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with enums. As enums are "implicitly final", and "An enum constant defines an instance of the enum type" [JLS 8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9), you can neither use inheritance nor define enum constants of a different type.

The closest thing I can think of would be something like

```
enum PrintablePersonTypes implements Printable {
   ADT(PersonTypes.ADT),
   CHD(PersonTypes.CHD), 
   INF(PersonTypes.INF);

   private PersonTypes pt;

   private PrintablePersonTypes(PersonTypes pt) {
       this.pt = pt;
   }

   @Override
   public void printme() {
        sysout("I'm a " + pt.value);
   }
}
```

i.e. explicitly creating the mapping via members.

Comment: That's neat! Any suggestion how I could further detect if the `PersonTypes` from the external library all of a sudden provide an additional type that I did not yet define in my `PrintablePersonTypes` mapping?

Comment: @membersound I'd probable catch that with a unit test, as this will require manually editing the code

Answer (score 2):

I would question whether you really need this method to be a member of the enum itself (or of any enum).

Enums are final, so there is no possibility of subclassing; so you would be effectively statically binding to an implementation of the method if it were an instance member of the enum.

Instead, define a static method in some other class:

```
public static void printme(PersonTypes pt) {
    sysout("I'm a " + pt.value);
}
```

And then just invoke this in your stream:

```
list.stream.forEach(SomeOtherClass::printme);
```

Answer (score 1):

Enums in java are final and not designed to be subclassed. If you must use custom enum and not for example `Map<String,whatever>`, you can define your enum as wrapper

```java
    enum PrintablePersonTypes implements Printable {
       ADT(PersonTypes.ADT),
       CHD(PersonTypes.CHD),
       INF(PersonTypes.INF);
    
       private PrintablePersonTypes(PersonTypes wrapped) {
           this.wrapped = wrapped;
       }

       PersonTypes wrapped;

       @Override
       public void printme() {
            sysout("I'm a " + wrapped.name());
       }
    }
```

You might then want to solve some sync with original enum. Deletion is for free and on compiler level (your enum just breaks if original enum constant is deleted). Addition is not so easy - you can utilize `switch` by enum or checking against map of names, but it is everything runtime issue, not compiletime.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
public class PrintablePersonTypes implements Printable {
   private PersonTypes me;
   private List<PersonTypes> allValues = PersonTypes.values();

   public getAllValues() {
       return allValues;
   }

   public PrintablePersonTypes(final PersonTypes personTypes) {
       this.me = personTypes;
   }

   @Override
   public void printme() {
        sysout("I'm a " + me);
   }
}
```

And later on:

```
List<PrintablePersonTypes> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new PrintablePersonTypes(PersonTypes.INF));
list.stream.forEach(p -> o.printme());
```